# Sort Not Working - Accessing Data with JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, sorting, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I've been playing with the Spring "Accessing Data with JPA" starter, adding my own entity and the corresponding repository.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "orders", path = "orders")
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long> {
```

The controllerless routes work fine for simple paging, but there is nothing I can do to get sorting working.

There are two cases. One:

```
http://192.168.0.163:8080/orders?sort=order_id&order_id.dir=desc
```

In this case the sort argument has no effect. No matter what combination I try, the sort order is unaffected. I have turned on show queries in STS, and no "order by" clause is generated.

The second case is for some field names in sort=, there is a null pointer exception in Spring:

```
2016-10-07 14:32:48.426 DEBUG 8292 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Error resolving argument [1] [type=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController]
Method [public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]


java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator$SortTranslator.translateSort(JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator.java:101) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator.translateSort(JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.MappingAwareDefaultedPageableArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(MappingAwareDefaultedPageableArgumentResolver.java:73) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
...
```

I just downloaded STS and the starter this week so they should be the latest versions.

Comment: More information - when sort=xxx where xxx is not an accessor name for the entity, it doesn't crash, but it doesn't sort. This includes xxx where xxx is a column name in the entity class. However, if xxx is any of the camel cased column names (i.e. matching an accessor), the null pointer exception occurs. Just upgraded to STS 3.8.2 - same behaviour.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue :<

Answer (score 0):

Too late, however.... avoid using underscores (e.g. 'aaa_bbb')  inside property/field/getters-setters names of your Entities....